# Different ${pageContext.response.locale} from chrome and firefox

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, locale

In a JSP, i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/library/validate_localization/messages_${pageContext.response.locale}.js"/>"></script>
```

to include validation messages for different locales ( messages_en.js ... messages_it.js ... etc etc )

In chrome it's everything ok, but in firefox, the browser try to include messages_en-US.js ... messages_it-IT.js .... how i can get always the same locale code in all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, but with Chrome adding -es_US, while firefox behaves good... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
${pageContext.response.locale.language}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.